# php sudo shell_exec command runs from command line, but not from browser

Tags: php, bash, lighttpd, sudo, shell-exec

I am running lighttpd with php-fpm.  I have added the http user to my sudoers, as a nopasswd sudoer.  I have the following script:

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec("sudo sh -c 'echo \"wtf3\" > /etc/openvpn/auth.txt'");
?>
```

It runs fine when I do:

```
sudo -u http php testsudo.php
```

but fails when run through the browser.

```
shell_exec("whoami");
```

confirms that I am user http when in browser.

What gives?

Comment: give the web server the proper permissions to write that file without need to be root

Comment: @hek2mgl not an option.. I need to edit several config files in etc, but i don't want my webserver to have carte blanche in those folders, so it's set in sudoers to only allow that one script to run as nopasswd.

Comment: What error does it get when you try this?

Comment: You think this is more secure, but it isn't. If there is a bug in the shellscript the door is wide open. Create a group `webmgmt` or whatever, transfer the group ownership of necessary files to that group and finally put http into that group

Comment: @Barmar it gives me no error whatsoever.  it simply doesn't do anything.  I was hoping to catch the error by running the script as http, in the shell, but it actually works when run that way.

Comment: @hek2mgl I am running several other scripts from the webserver, that do not require sudo.  some of them take user input and include it in commands.  Despite my sanitation, it would be a very bad idea to give those scripts editing capabilities in my etc folder.

both implementations have benefits and detriments, but I'm far more interested in why I'm getting inconsistent behavior with the implementation I have chosen.

Comment: @GregSchoppe What you are doing is bad, definitely. But however, if you encounter errors, why don't you have a look at the output of the command and it's return value? check the manual of `shell_exec()`

Comment: @hek2mgl the specific issue is that shell_exec returns null on error, so I can't see what happened.  After some googling, i found that adding 2>&1 to the command will pipe STD_ERR to STD_OUT, so i can see both.  I also simplified the test command to "sudo whoami".  The error in browser is "sudo: whoami: command not found".  Still no error when run from command line.

Comment: What gives you `var_dump(function_exists('shell_exec'));` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl bool(true) ... it's like shell_exec has forgotten the location of all the usr/bin commands

Comment: @GregSchoppe That's because the `$PATH` environment variable is likely not set. Use absolute paths for sudo and sh

Comment: Again, I would highly recomment to fix your file permissions in a way that shell scripts can work without need to be root

Comment: hmm... if I run  "echo $PATH" from terminal, it shows all my standard paths (including /usr/bin)... if I run "sudo echo $PATH" from terminal, it shows all my standard paths... if i run "sudo -u http echo $PATH" from terminal, it shows all my standard paths... if I run "sudo -u http sudo echo $PATH" from terminal, it shows all my standard paths...  if i run `echo shell_exec("echo $PATH");` in browser, it shows all my standard paths.  HOWEVER, if i run `echo shell_exec("sudo echo $PATH");` in the browser, the response is blank.

Comment: @hek2mgl PATH is set, and set the same for sudo, but in browser and only in browser, when shell_exec runs a sudo comand, it's returning blank.  It's forcing every command to require the full path, not just sudo. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: $PATH is not set *in webserver environment*. You can set this using .htaccess or use `putenv('PATH', '/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin: ....');` in php

Comment: @hek2mgl that did the trick... if you submit it as the answer, I'll set it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be out of the question to make a shell script that would run your command?

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo whoami
```

in the php:

```php
$retVal = `/path/to/custom/script/myscript.sh &2>1`;
if ($retVal) echo 'SWEET';
else echo 'POOP: ' . $retVal;
```

`{command}` inside `` means the same as `shell_exec('{command}')` on a linux server.
If I'm not way off base here your goal is to add users to your VPN (among other things perhaps) in which case you could pass command-line parameters for username/password/etc to your custom shell script.

It's not exactly a pure `shell_exec()` answer to your question, but maybe you can run `myscript.sh` without doing sudo.  Just basing this on the fact you said everything you tried worked in shell and path was set in `echo $PATH`, but not `sudo echo $PATH` in your PHP script.  Seems for some reason that sudo is an issue in php, but not in shell so...let's move the sudo back to shell and try it that way.